# What could have caused these black outlines

Tags: rendering

I tried to render an animation that I've made, by rendering each frame as a picture first, and I'm getting these black outlines. I have rendered this animation before and the produce didn't have any such outline, but I have tweaked and changed some things around since... I don't necessarily hate the lines, but it would be nice to know what might have caused them. Could it be the "Freestyle" setting, by any chance?
Thanks for your help!

[image: one render]

Comment: It does indeed look like Freestyle. If you turn it off (Properties Panel->Render tab->Freestyle setting) what happens?

Comment: yes, it did turn out to be Freestyle, thanks